# Get value from a controls in other thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, invoke

How can I get in WPF application, value from slider control in other thread?

To set value I use:

```
public static class ControlExtensions
    {
        public static void InvokeIfRequired(this Control control, Action action)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread != control.Dispatcher.Thread)
                control.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
            else
                action();
        }
        public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this Control control, Action<T> action, T parameter)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread != control.Dispatcher.Thread)
                control.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, parameter);
            else
                action(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Method call:

```
ControlExtensions.InvokeIfRequired(_mw, value => _mw.tb_w3.Text = value, godz_w3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this should work, you're just extracting the value to the variable `text` instead of assigning it to the `Text` property of what I'll assume is a `TextBox`

```
string text;
_mw.InvokeIfRequired(value => text = _mw.Text);
```